# How to downgrade mongoshell version 4.4 to 3.6?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-20.04

I'm having mongodb version conflict.
On the server, mongodb version 3.6 is already installed.
But I didn't know and tried to install mongodb 4.4 lts version. Now in the terminal, I'm having `WARNING: shell and server versions do not match` in the terminal.

```sh
MongoDB shell version v4.4.6
MongoDB server version: 3.6.8
```

I wanna downgrade only mongo shell version to 3.6.8 in order to be compatible with server in safe way.

Comment: Simply download desired version from https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community and install, e.g. https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-shell-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-3.6.23.tgz - Select package "shell" rather than "server"

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks. I will try it.