# Downgrading mongoDB from 4.4 to 3.6

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-20.04

I am working in Ubuntu 20.04 and I have previously installed mongodb `v4.4`. Due to some requirements I want to downgrade both my "shell" and "db" to `3.6` to function on the server. I am coming from this [How to downgrade mongoshell version 4.4 to 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67802950/how-to-downgrade-mongoshell-version-4-4-to-3-6)

But it seems it is not downloading [image]

Is there any other technique by which I can have this version?

Comment: In general should be no problem. Just be aware in 4.4 and later the `mongo-tools` are released as separate package. In version 3.6 they where part of the `mongo-org` package. This may required some manual work on your machine. Maybe you have to download old versions manually from https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community

Comment: The repo at https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/mongodb-org/ has no package for MongoDB 3.6 for Ubuntu 20.04, so you won't be able to get it from apt.

Comment: Is there a way manually that I can install it?